# Missing script: start in JHipster

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, jhipster

After creating a JHipster project, I get the following message:

```
 Spring Boot application generated successfully.
  Run your Spring Boot application:
  ./mvnw (mvnw if using Windows Command Prompt)
```

When I run ./mvnw, I get a build successful message, but nothing happens. So I tried running npm start, but I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
```

The only start I have in my package.json is "app:start": "./mvnw", so I don't know if I need to add this the start script to my package.json, and if I do, I don't know what it should be pointing to. Any help?

Comment: Which operating system are you running on? Which version of nodejs? run `node -v`. I don't know how you generated your project, but if you look at the sample project, its `package.json` has a `start` script https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/package.json#L67

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 with Node v20.3.1. I tried using the start script from the sample project, but I get this error message: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: node v20.3.1 is not a LTS release, JHipster supports only LTS. https://nodejs.dev/fr/about/releases/ More, JHipster 7 has some issues with Node 18 that will be fixed in JHipster 8. **So, for now, use Node 16**.https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v16.x/ Then you are on Windows, which shell are you using? To use the sample project, you must run `npm install` in it because you did not generate the project.

Comment: The issue is I was using jabba as well which only works with Node 18 and up.

Comment: So you should use JHipster 8 even if it's still in beta version, it's the only version that works with node 18. But maybe this is already what you use because it's the current default when you npm install -g generator-jhipster